# number of rows return different in mysql

Tags: mysql

For query first i make the aggregated table,pre-processing table like using below query

> 1. query no. 1

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS aggregated;
CREATE VIEW aggregated as 
SELECT 
`date`,
district,
town,
locality,
vendor,
freq_kind,
bandwidth,
circle_id,
SUM(data_total),
SUM(capacity),
CASE WHEN (SUM(IFNULL(data_total,0))/SUM(IFNULL(capacity,0))) * 100 < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS productivity 
FROM (
SELECT
circle_id, 
`date`,
district,town,locality,vendor,freq_kind,bandwidth, 
site_id,
`download`+`upload` AS data_total,

CASE WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "20 MHz" THEN 105
WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "15 MHz" THEN 80
WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "10 MHz" THEN 45
ELSE 0 END  AS capacity
FROM websites WHERE `date` = "2020-03-28"  AND upload IS NOT NULL AND download IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(site_id) != 'na' AND site_id IS NOT NULL) AS aa GROUP BY site_id
HAVING productivity =1
```

if i make the query

```
select count(*) from aggregated where circle_id = '102' and district = 'East'
```

It return 98 rows;

If i add this condition also with query no.1 then where clause so final looks like

```
WHERE `date` = "2020-03-28" and `circle_id = '102' and district = 'East'  AND download IS NOT NULL AND upload IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(site_id) != 'na' AND site_id IS NOT NULL) AS aa GROUP BY site_id
HAVING productivity =1
```

then it
return 101 ; which is correct ; where i am wrong.

For more if run the query like as below

```
SELECT 
`date`,
district,
town,
locality,
vendor,
freq_kind,
bandwidth,
circle_id,
SUM(data_total),
SUM(capacity),
CASE WHEN (SUM(IFNULL(data_total,0))/SUM(IFNULL(capacity,0))) * 100 < 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS productivity 
FROM (
SELECT
circle_id, 
`date`,
district,town,locality,vendor,freq_kind,bandwidth, 
site_id,
`download`+`upload` AS data_total,

CASE WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "20 MHz" THEN 105
WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "15 MHz" THEN 80
WHEN freq_kind = "2300" AND bandwidth = "10 MHz" THEN 45
ELSE 0 END  AS capacity
FROM websites WHERE `date` = "2020-03-28" and `circle_id = '102' and district = 'East'  AND download IS NOT NULL AND upload IS NOT NULL AND LOWER(site_id) != 'na' AND site_id IS NOT NULL) AS aa GROUP BY site_id
    HAVING productivity =1
```

The above query will return 101 rows;

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem? Your query has 102 in circle_id and you say it returns 101 "which is correct"

Comment: if i fetch the data from the aggregated table with with circle_id = 102 and district = east ; it return 98 rows; what when i run the raw query without aggregate query and add all in where clause it return 101 rows;

Comment: i am editing further my question

Comment: @PedroCarvalho did you got?

Comment: You have no proper `group by` clause, which MySQL allows depending on system setting. Try adding that clause.

Comment: @Bohemian please explain.

Comment: @david the group by clause only mentions site - to work properly it must list all non aggregate columns.

Comment: @Bohemian I need to aggregate only based on site after that i need to filter based on different column circle,district,town and locality; how the final query will looks like;i need to only get the number of rows return;

Comment: @Bohemian; i need to make the calculation based on site_id; after that i need to get the number of rows return like circle_id - > distrcit - > town - > locality

Comment: @davidjac mysql's non-sql standard group by will return randomly selected values for district,
town,
locality,
vendor,
freq_kind,
bandwidth,
circle_id, etc, although it will return 1 row per site.